# Regex match for starting character or _\w

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace start character or any _\w with uppercase. Here is my code

```
cmbServiceOffering.Items.Add(Regex.Replace(so.ToString().ToLower(), "($\\w|_\\w)", 
                new MatchEvaluator(
                      m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()
                   )));
```

But it does not match the start character. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modifier of start of regex is `^` not `$`. `$` is the end of regex modifier.

You need change your regex to following

```
"(^\\w|_\\w)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `^` and not `$`.. following will work:

```
(^\\w|_\\w)
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string or line (if `MULTILINE` flag is used)
- `$` end of the string or line (if `MULTILINE` flag is used)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookbehind based regex as well:

```
((?<=_|^)\\w)
```